# Losing string reference inside function

Tags: javascript, scope

What I need to do is receive a list of strings and transform this in a list of functions that checks if a given key contains those respective strings. What I'm trying:

```
var words = ['f', 'b', 'b']; //I never know how this list is
for(i in words){
    var str = words[i];
    words[i] = function(key){
        return key.indexOf(str) > -1;
    }
}
```

After runnning this script, I was expecting to `words` to become this:

```
[
    function(key){
        return key.indexOf('f') > -1;
    },
    function(key){
        return key.indexOf('b') > -1;
    },
    function(key){
        return key.indexOf('b') > -1;
    }
]
```

But when I try `words[0]('foo')`, It's returning me `false`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also, [it's wrong to use `for in` enumerations to iterate arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: thanks! I didn't even know how to search about it.